# How to submit / save form from within the Edit form

Tags: react-admin

I would like to submit the `<Edit>` form from within the form itself, in order to instantly save the form state upon a simple change e.g. a boolean toggle.

I spent hours trying to find a simple way, and it doesnt seem to exist. The `handleSubmit[...]` function is only passed to the `actions` toolbar, and not to the input themselves.

In addition, there seems to be no context hook I can invoke that would provide me access to that function.

One solution I can think of is create a hidden `<SaveButton />` inside the `actions` props, with a `ref`. Then from the input, I can trigger the `<SaveButton />` from the Input. However this seems super hacky, and I would love to find a more straightforward solution.

Is there a theoretical reason why inputs cannot access the `submit` function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `useSaveContext` hook which is not yet documented:

```
import { useSaveContext } from 'react-admin';

const { save, saving } = useSaveContext();
```